# How to integrate firebase crashlytics to React Native Project?

Tags: firebase, react-native, crashlytics

I have integrated firebase crashlytics in my react native project. I followed the link https://rnfirebase.io/crashlytics/usage

@react-native-firebase/app was already there in project. I enabled crashlytics from firebase console and updated GoogleService-Info.plist in my project. I installed the crashlytics using
npm i @react-native-firebase/crashlytics
cd ios/ && pod install

I have latest version installed in my project https://www.npmjs.com/package/@react-native-firebase/crashlytics

Firebase crashlytics is not working at all, anyone please let me know the if i am missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Few things to check:

1. whether your app is connecting properly to firebase, otherwise firebase will not accept GoogleService-Info.plist.
2. Check GoogleService-Info.plist is correctly configured in Xcode as mentioned on the plugin page.
3. Remove node_modules folder and reinstall using npm or using yarn